# Could not find Bluetooth driver for HP Notebook - 15-bs179tx for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth, hp

```
A part of output produced by command:
```

```
sudo lshw -html > mySpecs.html
```

- id:               usb:1
- description:  Bluetooth wireless interface
- product:      802.11n WLAN Adapter
- vendor:       Realtek
- physical id:  4
- bus info:         usb@1:4
- version:      2.00
- serial:       00e04c000001
- capabilities:     bluetooth usb-1.10
- configuration:

  - driver    =   btusb
  - maxpower  =   500mA
  - speed =   12Mbit/s

[Here's a link for Laptop Specifications](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c05835980)

**Edit**

[I tried to turn it on.The next time I open bluetooth from dash it shows off.Visibility button is also greyed out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA33u.png)

Comment: It might included when you installed OS. You just need to turn it on.

Comment: Hi @KevalMehta . Please check out the edit.